# How can I target a specific size in megabytes when saving a JPEG in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, jpeg, file-size

I need to save several files as 20mb jpgs. When I save an image in Photoshop CS5 at 20mb, then go to that saved file in  my folder, it shows as a much smaller file. Is there a formula for hitting that target size? A ratio?

Answer (score 5):

JPEG file size is a meaningless measure, except as an optimization criterion for bandwith/diskspace considerations.

Since JPEG is optimized to compress areas with little detail, while preserving fine detail, compression is dependent on the details in the image. There is no way you could produce a 20mb file from eg. a plain white image, <s>no matter the dimensions</s> for any reasonable photo dimensions. On the other hand, a large image with a lot of fine detail will produce a large JPEG file when saved with a good quality setting.

So, in my opinion, you should review your requirements. There aren't a lot of reasons to require a *specific* JPEG file size, most often, you only need to respect a *maximum* size. To achive this, the "save for web" function offers a suitable option.

Comment: Great answer overall, but to be pedantic the statement *"There is no way you could produce a 20mb file from eg. a plain white image, no matter the dimensions"* is not true. JPEG divides the image up into 8x8 or (16x16) blocks for compression. It has to store *some* data per block even if there's no detail. The maximum dimensions supported by the JPEG format are 2^16 - 1. Creating a 65535 x 65535 plain white image in Photoshop and saving as a JPEG resulted in a 272MB file. You could go even larger using the progressive option, but I didn't have enough memory available to perform that operation!

Comment: -1 for "JPEG file size is a meaningless measure." If I'm shoving it out over a mobile or other low bandwidth network it's incredibly relevant.

Comment: it's meaningless to require a *specific* file size. "as low as possible while maintaining visual quality" is of course different.

Comment: @PhilipKendall If you read the whole answer it's clear ths is referring to *minimum* filesizes as being a meaningless measure.

Comment: +1 for "JPEG file size is a meaningless measure" as this case is posted. Maximum file size, yes, that have sense.